# Dynamic SQL Pivot Table with moving Months

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create a rolling 12 months sales history through an SQL Query & Pivot Table. The program we use (SAP B1) only has a simple SQL editor so im hoping the below can be done. I have looked around and have found various Dynamic SQL queries which our system hasn't seemed to have liked too much. I essentially want to replace the months with something like 
    Month(getdate())

The Query

```
SELECT *
FROM  
(
    SELECT T0.ItemCode,SUM(T0.Quantity) AS Quantity, T0.WhsCode AS 'Warehouse',CONVERT(varchar,datepart(MONTH,t1.docdate)) PERIOD
    FROM INV1 T0
    INNER JOIN OINV T1 on T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry
    WHERE T1.Canceled = 'N' 
    AND T0.ItemCode = '75910' AND DATEDIFF(m, T0.DocDate,getdate()) < 12 
    GROUP BY T0.ItemCode, T0.WhsCode,CONVERT(varchar,datepart(YEAR,T1.DocDate)) ,CONVERT(varchar,datepart(MONTH,T1.DocDate))
    ) S  
PIVOT (SUM(QUANTITY) FOR [PERIOD] IN  
([7],[6],[5],[4],[3],[2],[1],[12],[11],[10],[9],[8])) P
```

Period simply returns the month of the DocDate. Then the Pivot goes by Calendar year (7 = July, 6 = June etc.) So the current month is listed first.
I would like the bottom part to be something along the lines of the below, however it doesnt work.

```
(Month(GetDate()),Month(GetDate())-1,Month(GetDate())-2 etc.)) P
```

to get "7", "6" right back to 8.

I hope that makes sense. Is something similar possible? Or would it have to be done by a more advanced Dynamic query?

This is what i am looking to return, but with the Periods at the bottom updating when a new month begins.
[image]

Comment: You can't produce the month names as column names without using a dynamic query. You _can_ produce the numbers themselves in order, though (e.g. `FOR [PERIOD] IN ([1], [2]...` by changing the PERIOD to something like `(12 + datepart(month, getdate()) - datepart(month, mydate)) % 12 + 1` where [1] will be the current month, [2] the previous month, etc). But to produce the actual month names in the pivot would require dynamic SQL.

Comment: That sounds like it could work as the month numbers would be ideal. Although im not too sure where to add the part you mentioned above? If i change it at the top of the query, it throws syntax errors? I have added a picture if that helps. Thanks!

Comment: You would add it as the "period" in the from statement. So like `SELECT T0.ItemCode,SUM(T0.Quantity) AS Quantity, T0.WhsCode AS 'Warehouse', (12 + datepart(month, getdate()) - datepart(month, t1.docdate)) % 12 + 1 PERIOD...` and then change the pivot to be `[1],[2],[3]...` I haven't tested this but it should work (you also shouldn't need to convert the PERIOD to varchar)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I tried it but gives the same result (the columns go in order of the Pivot, rather than the current month first). Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Well, the order of the pivot ([1],[2],[3],[4] etc) should be the current month as [1], the previous month as [2], the month before that as [3], and so on... That will never change. If you ran it in august, August would be [1]. If you ran it in December, December would be [1]. Unfortunately, there's no way to change the numbers (e.g. have it be 7,6,5,4 in july, 8,7,6,5 in august, etc) but the method I suggested will always do it in a way that's about as close as you can get without dynamic SQL.

Comment: Your other option is to do a long and tedious set of case statements in your select. Such that you'll always select the current month's column first... But this is rather tedious. I'll write out an example as an answer, maybe.

Answer (score 2):

So two options you have here...

The first is to change your pivot to be like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM  
(
    SELECT T0.ItemCode,SUM(T0.Quantity) AS Quantity, T0.WhsCode AS 'Warehouse', (12 + DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) - DATEPART(MONTH, t1.docDate)) % 12 + 1 PERIOD
    FROM INV1 T0
    INNER JOIN OINV T1 on T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry
    WHERE T1.Canceled = 'N' 
    AND T0.ItemCode = '75910' AND DATEDIFF(m, T0.DocDate,getdate()) < 12 
    GROUP BY T0.ItemCode, T0.WhsCode,datepart(YEAR,T1.DocDate),datepart(MONTH,T1.DocDate)
    ) S  
PIVOT (SUM(QUANTITY) FOR [PERIOD] IN  
([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])) P
```

This will produce itemcode, warehouse, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 as columns where 1 will always be the current month, 2 will always be the previous month, 3 will be the month before that, etc...

It's inconvenient because you have to actually work out what the month values are but this will always do it in this order.

Your other option is... a little more tedious... You'll need to use a whole bunch of IF statements to produce the results you want. For example,

```
IF DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) = 1 
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM  
    (
        SELECT T0.ItemCode,SUM(T0.Quantity) AS Quantity, T0.WhsCode AS 'Warehouse',datepart(MONTH,t1.docdate) PERIOD
        FROM INV1 T0
        INNER JOIN OINV T1 on T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry
        WHERE T1.Canceled = 'N' 
        AND T0.ItemCode = '75910' AND DATEDIFF(m, T0.DocDate,getdate()) < 12 
        GROUP BY T0.ItemCode, T0.WhsCode, datepart(YEAR,T1.DocDate), datepart(MONTH,T1.DocDate)
        ) S  
    PIVOT (SUM(QUANTITY) FOR [PERIOD] IN  
    ([1],[12],[11],[10],[9],[8],[7],[6],[5],[4],[3],[2])) P
END 
ELSE IF DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) = 2
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM  
    (
        SELECT T0.ItemCode,SUM(T0.Quantity) AS Quantity, T0.WhsCode AS 'Warehouse',datepart(MONTH,t1.docdate) PERIOD
        FROM INV1 T0
        INNER JOIN OINV T1 on T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry
        WHERE T1.Canceled = 'N' 
        AND T0.ItemCode = '75910' AND DATEDIFF(m, T0.DocDate,getdate()) < 12 
        GROUP BY T0.ItemCode, T0.WhsCode, datepart(YEAR,T1.DocDate), datepart(MONTH,T1.DocDate)
        ) S  
    PIVOT (SUM(QUANTITY) FOR [PERIOD] IN  
    ([2],[1],[12],[11],[10],[9],[8],[7],[6],[5],[4],[3])) P -- note this part changes depending on the datepart(month, getdate()) value
END 
ELSE IF DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) = 3
BEGIN
    ...
```

Essentially, write out twelve different if statements here. BUT one advantage this does have is that rather than having numbers for the months, you can use month names if you alter the query slightly... For example,

```
IF DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) = 1 
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM  
    (
        SELECT T0.ItemCode,SUM(T0.Quantity) AS Quantity, T0.WhsCode AS 'Warehouse', months.name PERIOD
        FROM INV1 T0
        INNER JOIN OINV T1 on T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry
        INNER JOIN (VALUES (1, 'Jan'), (2, 'Feb'), (3, 'Mar'), (4, 'Apr'), (5, 'May'), (6, 'Jun'), (7, 'Jul'), (8, 'Aug'), (9, 'Sep'), (10, 'Oct'), (11, 'Nov'), (12, 'Dec')) months(num, name) ON datepart(MONTH, T1.DocDate) = months.num
        WHERE T1.Canceled = 'N' 
        AND T0.ItemCode = '75910' AND DATEDIFF(m, T0.DocDate,getdate()) < 12 
        GROUP BY T0.ItemCode, T0.WhsCode, datepart(YEAR,T1.DocDate), datepart(MONTH,T1.DocDate)
        ) S  
    PIVOT (SUM(QUANTITY) FOR [PERIOD] IN  
    ([Jan],[Dec],[Nov],[Oct],[Sep],[Aug],[Jul],[Jun],[May],[Apr],[Mar],[Feb])) P
END 
ELSE IF DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) = 2
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM  
    (
        SELECT T0.ItemCode,SUM(T0.Quantity) AS Quantity, T0.WhsCode AS 'Warehouse', months.name PERIOD
        FROM INV1 T0
        INNER JOIN OINV T1 on T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry
        INNER JOIN (VALUES (1, 'Jan'), (2, 'Feb'), (3, 'Mar'), (4, 'Apr'), (5, 'May'), (6, 'Jun'), (7, 'Jul'), (8, 'Aug'), (9, 'Sep'), (10, 'Oct'), (11, 'Nov'), (12, 'Dec')) months(num, name) ON datepart(MONTH, T1.DocDate) = months.num
        WHERE T1.Canceled = 'N' 
        AND T0.ItemCode = '75910' AND DATEDIFF(m, T0.DocDate,getdate()) < 12 
        GROUP BY T0.ItemCode, T0.WhsCode, datepart(YEAR,T1.DocDate), datepart(MONTH,T1.DocDate)
        ) S  
    PIVOT (SUM(QUANTITY) FOR [PERIOD] IN  
    ([Feb],[Jan],[Dec],[Nov],[Oct],[Sep],[Aug],[Jul],[Jun],[May],[Apr],[Mar])) P -- note this part changes depending on the datepart(month, getdate()) value
END
ELSE IF DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) = 3 
BEGIN
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use below method to get months for pivot,

```
SELECT  Month(GetDate())
        ,Month(DateAdd(MONTH,-1,GetDate()))
        ,Month(DateAdd(MONTH,-2,GetDate()))
        ,Month(DateAdd(MONTH,-3,GetDate()))
        ,Month(DateAdd(MONTH,-4,GetDate()))
        ,Month(DateAdd(MONTH,-5,GetDate()))
        ,Month(DateAdd(MONTH,-6,GetDate()))
        ,Month(DateAdd(MONTH,-7,GetDate()))
        ,Month(DateAdd(MONTH,-8,GetDate()))
        ,Month(DateAdd(MONTH,-9,GetDate()))
        ,Month(DateAdd(MONTH,-10,GetDate()))
        ,Month(DateAdd(MONTH,-11,GetDate()))
```